# How can I convert just one of the components used in my React app into a widget

Tags: javascript, reactjs, widget, vite, react-widgets

I have a react app created using Vite, which has 4 components that are material ui tables that display some info. I want one of them to be a widget so it can be used in the current app and other apps by putting the URL of it in an Iframe.

I have seen articles online around converting a whole app into a widget but in my case I just want to convert one component into a widget.

Answer (score 0):

Create a React component that you want to use as a widget. Make sure the component is self-contained and does not depend on the global state of your main app.
Example:

```
    import React from 'react';
    import { YourTableComponent } from './YourTableComponent';
    
    const WidgetComponent = () => {
      return (
        <div>
          <h2>Widget Title</h2>
          <YourTableComponent />
          {/* Add other necessary components */}
        </div>
      );
    };
    
    export default WidgetComponent;
```

After you will need to create a page that will serve as the entry point for your widget.

```
    import WidgetComponent from '../components/WidgetComponent';
    
    const WidgetPage = () => {
      return <WidgetComponent />;
    };
    
    export default WidgetPage;
```

Then you can place your iframe where you want like

```
<iframe
  title="Your Widget"
  src="http://localhost:3000/widget"
  ...
></iframe>
```

Hope it will help.
I tryed on next.js project and looks Ok for me.

You can check the vite.config file here too:

```
export default {
  build: {
    lib: {
      entry: 'src/WidgetComponent.js',
      name: 'WidgetComponent',
    },
  },
};
```

Comment: thanks for replying, If I have tests and a style sheet for that component also I am passing in data into that table component via props so getting data just from a javascript file. Would I have to create a widget folder that would contain the widget.js, widget entry point, tests, style sheet and the data javascript file ? Then build the whole folder in the vite.config for it to be stand alone.